# Не могу вывести текст в label при считывании из JTextField

Tags: java, eclipse

```
    btnNewButton = new JButton("ok");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        private String i;
        private String a;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            i = textField.getText();
            a = "Abandon";
            if(i == a){
                lblNewLabel.setText("Abandon");
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Изменение текста у метки должно выполняться в потоке событий swing. Попробуйте так:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        if ("Abadon".equals(textField.getText()))
            lblNewLabel.setText("Abadon");
        else
            myLabel.setText("my text");
    });
}
```

А вообще, у вас ошибка в коде, строки нужно сравнивать методом `equals`

Comment: синтаксическая ошибка + я начинающий и не знаю многих методов а тем что меня учили очень много не включает

Comment: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Comment: Я поправил код, ошибка не должна появиться

Comment: она естьbtnNewButton = new JButton("ok");
   private String i;
   private String a;

   public actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
           if ("Abadon".equals(textField.getText()))
               lblNewLabel.setText("Abadon");
           else
               lblNewLabel.setText("my text");
       });
   }

Comment: ошибка в arg0 invalid modifers

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "(", . expected
 - Illegal modifier for parameter arg0; only final is 
  permitted
 - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

Comment: приложи весь код, из комментариев не очень понятно

Comment: btnNewButton = new JButton("ok");
   private String i;
   private String a;

   public actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
           if ("Abadon".equals(textField.getText()))
               lblNewLabel.setText("Abadon");
           else
               lblNewLabel.setText("my text");
       });
   }

Comment: и ошибка в args0

Comment: весь код не могу превыение символов

Comment: pastebin.com или gist.github.com/

Comment: создал с тем же заголовком на гист

Comment: могу в контакте вкинуть

Comment: дай линк на gist

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c230ddbfa39ef7039d713684f69f4767/revisions

Comment: строка 116, в определении метода пропущен возвращаемый тип и модификаторы доступа у локальных переменных i и a, не нужно указывать

Comment: btnNewButton = new JButton("ok");
   public void String i;
   public void String a;

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0); {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
           if ("Abadon".equals(textField.getText()))
               lblNewLabel.setText("Abadon");
           else
               lblNewLabel.setText("my text");
       });
   }
&&

Comment: Хм. Тебе нужно повторить теорию, как объявляются переменные, методы, классы, что такое final, static поля, области видимости. После этого можно попробовать писать программы, но не трогай пока swing.